# Opening word doc from VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have a subroutine in MS Access that opens a specific word doc file.  The gist of the code is

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim filepath as String

'Open Word
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True

filepath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Prospect Profiles\Account Profile Form.doc"

'Open the file
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(filepath)
```

So here's the kicker - The subroutine works for all but one of our employees.  We're all on the same Citrix environment, and we all have the same version of Access and Word.  For this user, the subroutine does not give an error - it smiply opens a blank instance of ms word but it never opens the word doc file.  What gives?

Comment: Can that employee open `Account Profile Form.doc` manually once Word is running?

Comment: Yes, he can open the file manually with no problem

Comment: Just check if the user has adequate rights to the folder.

Comment: From within that VBA procedure does `Dir(filepath)` return the file name?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! It turns out that this user had made a copy of an older version of our database front end and he wasn't accessing our current, updated version.  Thanks for all the help y'all!

Comment: It's always a good idea to put a version check into the front-end, even with fancy automatic FE updaters in place. Now that people can "pin" an open Access front-end application (.accdb/.accde) to their taskbars there needs to be an independent check to make sure that users who have pinned an old version get an error when a new version is available.

Comment: Also have the app startup routine confirm the FE is located where expected.  IOW, is its `CurrentProject.Path` correct?